# Getting a 404 error for newly added .aspx page

Tags: asp.net

Why can't I simply add a new .aspx page to my running website without getting a 404 error?

Does the new page need to be registered in some file of the site??

I'll keep this question simple as to not confuse.

Comment: Did you also add the associated .designer.aspx.vb and .aspx.vb files and the new .dll (etc.) file(s) from the \bin directory?

Comment: I have no knowledge of any of that, sorry. It's a C# site if that helps. I was using an existing page as a template, which I thought would work. I have source code, but cannot rebuild the site from VS so I'm working with production code in my html editor. Shouldn't be so complicated as you're suggesting. Could you possibly guide me a bit. Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you rebuild the site in VS?

Comment: The VS code throw errors, apparently an endless loop somewhere.

Comment: If you're saying that VS is faulty, then the first stage should be to get it into a stable state. Reinstall it or repair it; either way make sure all the updates are installed too. Which version of VS are you using? Do you know which version of VS the site was made with?

Comment: VS is fine, it's the source code we purchased that throws errors. They also supplied us the production code which is working fine. Every time I do a small update, I start from the production code and also make the changes to the source code, just in case I do have an opportunity to rebuild the project.

Comment: These are minor html and java changes and sometimes a simple database sort change - what ever I can figure out at this point since I'm still starting out in VS projects. My concern is not the throw exceptions, rather what would be the easiest solution (using production code) to add a new page. The page needs to keep all the Site Master framework and such. Thanks